# What's the difference between Task.Yield, Task.Run, and ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

As I understand it, `Task.Yield` at the beginning of a method will force the caller to continue if it is not awaiting the method. Meanwhile `Task.Run` and `ConfigureAwait(false)` [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906092/what-are-the-differences-between-using-configureawaitfalse-and-task-run) run a Task on a new thread pool thread, which again will force the caller to continue if it is not awaiting the method.

I can't understand the difference between `Task.Yield` and running a new thread pool thread, since right after it returns to the caller, it will continue executing the rest of the method, which is essentially the same thing.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320899/4077294) post suggests that `Yield` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` (which is really just the old version of `Task.Run`) can be used interchangeably, which seems confusing to me.

Comment: Task.Run = Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: @hungndv `Task.Run` is `Task.Factory.StartNew` but on the Default Task Scheduler (The thread pool task scheduler). `Task.Factory.StartNew`without specifying a task scheduler will pick the current task scheduler, which may not be the default one. It could be the UI task scheduler for instance. `Task.Run` always executes in the threadpool.

So, `Task.Run` is a special case of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and **not** the new version of it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`Task.Yield` is not a replacement for `Task.Run` and it has nothing to do with `Task.ConfigureAwait`**.

- `Task.Yield` - Generates an awaitable that completes just after it is checked for completion.
- `ConfigureAwait(false)` - Generates an awaitable from a task that disregards the captured `SynchronizationContext`.
- `Task.Run` - Executes a delegate on a `ThreadPool` thread.

`Task.Yield` is different than `ConfigureAwait` in that it is an awaitable all by itself, and not a configurable wrapper of another awaitable (i.e. the `Task`). Another difference is that `Task.Yield` does continue on the captured context.

`Task.Run` is different then both as it just takes a delegate and runs it on the `ThreadPool`, you can use it with `ConfigureAwait(false)` or without.

`Task.Yield` should be used to force an asynchronous point, not as a replacement to `Task.Run`. When await is reached in an async method it checks whether the task (or other awaitable) already completed and if so it continues on synchronously. `Task.Yield` prevents that from happening so it's useful for testing.

Another usage is in UI methods, where you don't want to be hogging the single UI thread, you insert an asynchronous point and the rest is scheduled to be executed in a later time.

Comment: `Task.Yield` doesn't work to avoid UI throttling, because the UI message queues are prioritized (and continuations always take precedence over `WM_PAINT`).

Comment: Also you never want to paint as fast as you can. That burns one core for nothing.

Comment: @StephenCleary : who posts the continuations in the UI message queue ? This can only happen if some BeginInvoke is called at some point right

Comment: @v.oddou: Follow-up questions should be their own question (SO is a Q&A site, not a forum). Short answer: `await` will post the method continuation to the current `SynchronizationContext` instance, which uses `BeginInvoke` (or equivalent) under the covers.

Answer (score 7):

`Task.Yield` continues on the current synchronization context or on the current `TaskScheduler` if one is present. `Task.Run` does not do that. It always uses the thread-pool.

For example `Task.Yield` would stay on the UI thread.

Avoid `Task.Yield`. It's semantics are less clear. The linked answer is a code smell.

Comment: A good point about the use of `TaskScheduler.Current` by `Task.Yield` - another questionable design decision of the TPL team. And this one cannot be justified by .NET 4.0 compatibility reasons, as there's no `Task.Yield` in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Noseratio How is it questionable? `await` continues on the captured context unless explicitly told otherwise which is a safe default. Why should it be different with `Task.Yield`.

Comment: @i3arnon, I'm not questioning the `Task.Yield` behavior when synchronization context is present. But in the absence of one, I'm questioning the use of `TaskScheduler.Current` vs `TaskScheduler.Default`. I strongly believe the latter should have been used, as it is with `Task.Run`.

Comment: I really wouldn't call the default choice of resuming on some configurable context a safe choice! It is convenience for UI apps but besides that it is very dangerous. A hidden dependency on mutable global state that can inject arbitrary threading behavior. Very unsafe.

Comment: @Noseratio I wasn't talking about the SC as well. `await` resumes on the current TS, there's no reason it should be any different with `Task.Yield`. `Task.Run` has nothing to do with `Task.Yield`, it explicitly executes code on a different TS.

Comment: @usr If it's convenient for UI apps (and asp.net apps as well) then that's the safe choice. It's not without its issues, but there would be much more if they didn't take these dependencies.

Comment: @i3arnon, in the absence of SC, the use of `TaskScheduler.Current` for `await` was IMO a bad decision, too. A very non-intuitive and subtle behavior. Toub gives a good example of how it all can go wrong [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx).